# ¿Como cambiar icono a posición opuesta con css?

Tags: css, style

Tengo el siguiente icono:

```
<i class="fa fa-truck fa-2x " style="color:#155724;position:absolute;top:9px; "></i>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito que el icono del camión este apuntando hacia a la izquierda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con rotate 180 y -180, pero no me resulta, queda el icono con las ruedas hacia arriba:

```
<i style="color:#155724;position:absolute;top:9px;-webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg)" class="fa fa-truck fa-2x "></i>
```

Me gustaría saber si existe una forma de hacerlo, y como.

Desde ya, gracias.
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, todas son útiles, pero le doy como solución final al primero que me respondió...Saludos, son muy buenas sus respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso puedes lograrlo con un `transform: scaleX(-1);`, basicamente le estás indicando que quieres escalarlo en negativo pero a escala 1:1, exactamente mismo tamaño... pero al revés.

Answer (score 2):

Si estás usando font awesome, puedes hacerlo con: **'data-fa-transform="flip-h"'**

```
 <i class="fa fa-truck fa-2x" data-fa-transform="flip-h"></i>
```

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/power-transforms

Comment: Interesante, no conocía esa funcionalidad de sus iconos!

Answer (score 0):

Bastaria con agregarle la clase fa-flip-horizontal

```
<i class="fas fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>
```

Aca podes probarlo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      
      <h1 class="title">
        Hello World
        <br /><br />
        <!-- Icono normal-->
        <i class="fas fa-truck"></i>
        <br /><br />
        <!-- Icono invertido horizontalmente-->
        <i class="fas fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>
      </h1>
      <p class="subtitle">
        My first website with <strong>Bulma</strong>!
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.